# OutOfMemoryException while reading .csv

Tags: .net, vb.net, csv, out-of-memory

I've a console application where I need to read a few .csv files.
I've no problem to read the two first wich are quite ligth (about 10 000 records each).
But when it start reading the third one (way heavier, about 220 000 records) I keep having error "OutOfMemoryException was unhandled: An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

I don't understand seen it s working fine for the two first csv...

Here's my function reading the csv files, the error occurs on the split:

```
Function FileToString(filePath As String) As String()
    Dim myfile As New StreamReader(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"))
    Dim allData As String = myfile.ReadToEnd()
    Dim rows As String() = allData.Split(vbCr.ToCharArray)
    Return rows
End Function
```

How could I prevent this? Is there a better way to read csv? 
Thanx

Comment: Do not read whole file at once.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse the CSV yourself instead of using one of the many CSV libraries out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things to consider

1) Instead of String use StringBuilder as
Dim builder As New StringBuilder

2) For file reading use buffered approach instead of myfile.ReadToEnd()

Example

```
Function FileToString(filePath As String) As String 
    Dim f As System.IO.FileStream
    Dim mylength As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    f = New System.IO.FileStreamfilePath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)

    Dim streamLength As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(f.Length)
    Dim fileData As Byte() = New Byte(streamLength) {}

    f.Read(fileData , 0, streamLength)
    f.Close()
    return fileData.ToString();
End Function
```

And if you want line by line then use below code

```
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("TestFile.txt")
Dim line As String
Do
    line = sr.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine(Line)
Loop Until line Is Nothing
sr.Close()
```

Comment: I'm kind of newbie in programming, how can I read line by line my file through the buffer?

Comment: Thx for your answer, but what am I suppose to do in the for loop? I can't get my file line by line...

Answer (score 0):

You should just read line by line, ReadToEnd will just load the full file content into memory, if you got big file you got OutOfMemoryException